# How to avoid denial of service (DoS) reading Google News RSS feeds

Tags: php, rss, access-denied

I have over 1000 clients and I developed a simple PHP script to loop through their names searching for any news using Google News RSS.

I loop this string substituting $searchString for the relevant name:

```
$GoogleSearch = "https://news.google.com/news/feeds?q=".$searchString."&output=rss";
```

I am also using a "call_user_func" in an attempt to control (serialize) the requests to Google (i.e. a "delegate method").

Trouble is Google is too smart for their own good and they detected my IP address sending these requests and they blocked my access!

Any suggestions how I can avoid a DoS?

Thanks.

Comment: So what you are asking is: "How do I scrape Google without them noticing? I need to know because they don't allow scraping and locks me out!" I'm only checking this so I don't accidentally help in unethical behavior.

Comment: @EmilVikström, Agreed, but the need is also legitimate.  I get the impression that Jeremy wouldn't mind hearing an alternate solution, even if it were an API with a pay tier.

Comment: There is a reason for google to do that. I think you should start searching for the answer on the question 'why?' instead of 'how to avoid'.

Comment: Hi Guys,  This is a legitimate request.  I don't have the time to manually search, so thought a simple script would help.  Is there a route to signing up as a "Google partner" so to speak?  I searched but could not find.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You probably just need to slow down the requests you're sending to google.  Either put pauses in your scripts or separate it so that it runs at different times for different clients.  For example, if you have 1000 clients, you could run one request every 3.6 seconds and you'd have all of your clients updated within an hour.